# Responsive list-style-image how to?

Tags: html, css, list, responsive-design, icons

i have this menu and on i have put on the main links list-style-image but it is not responsive and I want to make them responsive?

http://tinyurl.com/otwocvz

this is the demo

this is the code that puts in the icon and my unsuccessfull attempt to make them responsive

```
#cssmenu ul li   { list-style-image:url(ico.png); }
#cssmenu  li img {
width:auto;
height:100%;}
```

Comment: I don't even see your menu when resizing, not icons, but nothing at all

Comment: its only for desktop resolutions, for mobile its other menu that i use

Comment: Then why do you care for responsive sizes? Your icons are small enough to cover any desktop size and they won't go bigger than your `li` element. Either way, try to use the image as background instead of list-style-image and then simply apply a `max-height:100%` to your `li` and that's it

Comment: because the text is responsive, and in bigger screens gets bigger smaller screens gets smaller im talking about desktop only, i need the pic to be the same size as the height of the text in the menu. Other wise on 22 inch is one and on 15 other.

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: tried but could not do it the image goes behind the text and also on the li that I dont want to have points, i need points only on the main ones

Comment: you need to add `padding-left:30px (or whatever); list-style-type:none`